# Submitting form to localdb

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am currently new to and using Visual Studio Community / ASP.net, following along a tutorial which is using Visual Studio Express. It seems I have hit a road block as my form does not seem to submit to the LocalDB as it does in the tutorial.

Apparently, because VS Express (which I am not using) install comes preconfigured with a LocalDB instance. I have connected to my SQL Server LocalDb by clicking Tools > Connect to database.

My question is: why is the data entered in my form not being submitted and stored in a dynamically created table in my SQL Server database as it is in the tutorial? Any help will be much appreciated.

MODEL

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ExploreCalifornia.Models
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext() : base("Explore California")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Tour> Tours { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class TourController : Controller
{
    private MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();

    // GET: Tour
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
}

[HttpPost] //<--explicitly identified (difference from the other create() action above
public ActionResult Create(Tour tour)
{
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            db.Tours.Add(tour);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
}
```

Comment: All you are showing is the ability to pull a View from your controller. How do you insert the data?

Comment: i just updated my code to include the insert block of code

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: You've debugged and are hitting the post action with a populated tour? If so, then issue could be your connection string. What's it look like?

Comment: replace `catch` with `catch (Exception ex)` and set a breakpoint inside the catch-block to see if you get an exception

Comment: @mason no i don't

Comment: @SteveGreene My connection string is currently "Explore California" which should be a database created dynamically upon the submission of the form - per the tutorial instructions.

Comment: "Explore California" is not a connection string. That's the name of a connection string. Check in your web.config for the corresponding connection string.

Comment: BTW when i do submit the form the web page renders supposedly completes but the values remain in the input field. When i check the to see if the db/table has been created i find nothing

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in your Create action method to make sure that code gets reached?

Comment: See this on database connections. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592674.aspx